# How to tell if a tri dimensional square is a Latin Square

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array, latin-square

I need to design an algorithm that tells if a given matrix of integers is a valid latin square or not. I've never worked with Latin Sqares before so I don't know where to begin. After some research I only found algorithms for writing a Latin square. The only thing that occured to me is that the sum of all columns and rows should be the same but then I have to check for every number if it's repeated in that same row and column. Doing it that way the program will have a big time cost. I'm using C++.

Comment: Can you show us the "big time cost" version?  That would give us something to help you with.

Comment: All we can do for you is google for an answer - something that you can do yourself.  Without some code in place to help you work through, there is not much else to answer.

Comment: You are not making an effort to pose an appropriate question: please provide your attempts so far, and the outcome you expect.

Answer (score 0):

> Doing it that way the program will have a big time cost.

No, since you can reject a lot of matrix before you reach the end. So algorithm will fail fast. Worst estimation of working algorithm is `O(n*(n+1))` (I assuming that you evaluate only square matrix where dimension is n*n). But average algorithm will be much better - because it will fail as first in-equality found.

**Update:**
  The average complexity can be rough and approximately estimated as number of real Latin Squares to number of possible squares. To do this we need introduce understand `normalized` square. Two squares bellow are intuitively the same :

```
[ 1 2       [5 7
  2 1 ]      7 5]
```

So to normalize this we can use substitution for numbers 1...n of n*n square. So first form wins.

For normalized squares [Wiki provides an estimation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latin_square) [image]

Are you scared? But for average we also need to divide this formula by total number of matrix. To do this see this formula http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination

Comment: ok but my question is what is that average algorithm because I've been searching on google for hours even about sudoku and I still don't know what the principles of that algorithm